# Converting a list with numpy arrays into lists in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `B11` containing a list of numpy arrays. I want to convert each of these arrays into lists but I am getting an error. I also show the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

B11=[[np.array([353.856161,   0.      ,   0.      ]), 
      np.array([  0.      ,   0.      , 282.754301,   0.      ])], 
     [np.array([  0.      , 294.983702, 126.991664])]]

C11=B11.tolist()
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    C11=B11.tolist()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

The expected output is

```
[[[353.856161,   0.      ,   0.      ],[  0.      ,   0.      , 282.754301,   0.      ]],
 [  0.      , 294.983702, 126.991664]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in B11:
    for y in x:
        print(y.tolist())

#output:

[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]
[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]
```

Or List comprehension to keep the values:

```
[[y.tolist() for y in x] for x in B11]

#[[[353.856161, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 282.754301, 0.0]],
#[[0.0, 294.983702, 126.991664]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`B11` is already a python `list` - its elements are numpy arrays.
You're looking for something like `C11 = [sublist.tolist() for sublist in B11]`.

This will traverse `B11` and create a new list whose elements are constructed by calling the `.tolist()` method on each sublist from `B11`.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an error: ```in <listcomp>
    C11 = [sublist.tolist() for sublist in B11]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist' ```